# ¿Como puedo agrupar 2 tablas y contar la cantidad de filas?

Tags: mysql

Alguien podría ayudarme a como agrupar? Tengo esta consulta, lo que necesito es agruparlo la cantidad por "condición" y por "grupo_programa" es decir

Tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT at_ce.condicion, gpr.grupo_programa FROM at_cons_externa at_ce
INNER JOIN gen_programa gpr ON at_ce.id_programa = gpr.id_programa
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo agrupar con esta linea:

```
select condicion, count(*) as cantidad from at_cons_externa group by condicion
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero también quisiera agrupar "grupo_programa", en la misma sentencia y con la cantidad que le pertenece a cada uno, espero me puedan ayudar, Gracias...

Comment: Basta con agregar las columnas por las que quieres agrupar a la cláusula `GROUP BY`. ¿O necesitas construir una "tabla pivote"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder usar las funciones de agregamiento COUNT, SUM, etc. debes agrupar todas las otras columnas que no se contabilizan para contar, sumar, etc.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT at_ce.condicion, gpr.grupo_programa, count(*) 
   FROM at_cons_externa at_ce
        INNER JOIN gen_programa gpr ON at_ce.id_programa = gpr.id_programa
   GROUP BY at_ce.condicion, gpr.grupo_programa
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me sirvió. :)

Comment: @JeanPaul de nada colega!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes introducir los dos select en el from:

```
SELECT T_CONDICION.CONDICION, T_CONDICION.CANTIDAD, T_GRUPO.grupo_programa, T_GRUPO.CANTIDAD
FROM
(select condicion, count(*) as cantidad from at_cons_externa group by condicion) AS T_CONDICION,
(select grupo_programa, count(*) as cantidad from at_cons_externa group by grupo_programa)AS T_GRUPO
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta aceptada contiene lo que necesitas. Sólo para abonar al comentario que hice respecto de la "tabla pivote", te pongo aquí una opción para generarla.

A modo de ejemplo, los "encabezados de fila" serán los valores de `condicion` y los encabezados de columna serán los valores de `grupo_programa` (Generé 100 valores aleatorios para probar que esto funcionara bien).

Primero, pongamos los valores de interés en una tabla temporal, para ahorrarnos el escribir la misma consulta una y otra vez

```
drop table if exists temp_datos;
create temporary table temp_datos
SELECT at_ce.condicion, gpr.grupo_programa
FROM at_cons_externa at_ce
     INNER JOIN gen_programa gpr ON at_ce.id_programa = gpr.id_programa;
```

Para que esta solución funcione, es necesario garantizar que la función `GROUP_CONCAT()` puede devolver cadenas largas. Generalmente el valor que te propongo aquí es más que suficiente:

```
set session group_concat_max_len = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

Ahora viene lo bueno: Vamos a generar una lista de expresiones que sumen 1 para cada valor de la columna `grupo_programa` presente en la tabla, y cero en otro caso. Estas expresiones las guardaremos en una variable (`@sql`):

```
set @sql = (select group_concat(distinct concat("sum(case grupo_programa when '", grupo_programa, "' then 1 else 0 end) as `", grupo_programa, "`")) from temp_datos);
```

Vamos ahora a completar la consulta que estamos generando:

```
set @sql = concat('select condicion, ', @sql, ', count(*) as Total from temp_datos group by condicion with rollup');
```

Si quieres ver cómo quedo tu consulta completa, puedes verificarla así:

```
select @sql;
-- La variable SQL contiene la siguiente cadena de texto 
-- (agregué saltos de línea por claridad):
--
-- select condicion, 
-- sum(case grupo_programa when 'TARJETAS DE SALUD' then 1 else 0 end) as `TARJETAS DE SALUD`,
-- sum(case grupo_programa when 'INSTITUCIONAL/PRIVADOS' then 1 else 0 end) as `INSTITUCIONAL/PRIVADOS`, 
-- count(*) as Total 
-- from temp_datos 
-- group by condicion with rollup
```

Ahora sí, vamos a obtener los valores: Prepara y ejecuta la consulta que acabamos de crear:

```
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
```

El resultado:

```
condicion             | TARJETAS DE SALUD |  INSTITUCIONAL/PRIVADOS |  Total
----------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+-------
ANULADO POR ADMISION  |                11 |                      13 |     24
CONFIRMADO            |                16 |                       6 |     22
NO PASO CONSULTA      |                 8 |                      10 |     18
OBSERVADO             |                12 |                      10 |     22
RESERVADO             |                 8 |                       6 |     14
NULL                  |                55 |                      45 |    100
```

Esa última fila (con el valor `NULL` en la columna `condicion` contiene el total de cada columna (este valor se genera cuando utilizas `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`; si no lo necesitas, sólo quita `WITH ROLLUP`).

Cuando termines, no olvides "limpiar" la sentencia preparada:

```
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Espero esta solución te sea útil.

Saludos